# Nested generic types: Reuse function's Type parameter

Tags: go, templates

Given the following definitions:

```
type Collector[T, C any] interface {
    Collect(T, C) C
}

type mapCollector[K comparable, V any] struct {
    GetKey func(result V) K
}

func (m *mapCollector[K, V]) Collect(value V, c *sync.Map) *sync.Map {
    c.Store(m.GetKey(value), value)
    return c
}
```

I am trying to write a templated make function for `mapCollector`.
This does not work

```
func MakeUserMapCollector[K UserId, V User]() *mapCollector[K, V] {
    c := mapCollector[K, V]{
        GetKey: func(user V) K {
            return user.getId()
        }
    }
    return &c
}
```

Instead I have to be repetitive

```
func MakeUserMapCollector() *mapCollector[UserId, User] {
    c := mapCollector[UserId, User]{
        GetKey: func(user User) UserId {
            return user.getId()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reuse the `MakeUserMapCollector` type parameters to declare types in the function?

Comment: What are `UserId` and `User`? Structs, interfaces?

Comment: Also, `Collector` interface and `Collect` method are not relevant to your question, so you can remove them from the example (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic constructor function that accepts a function for "collection" and then passes it to your `mapCollector` struct.

That would look something like this:

```golang
func MakeUserMapCollector[K comparable, V any](collect func(result V) K) *mapCollector[K, V] {
    return &mapCollector[K, V]{
        GetKey: collect,
    }
}
```

Then you can call the constructor function with your types as type parameters and your "collection" function:

```golang
mc := MakeUserMapCollector[UserId, User](func(result User) UserId { return result.GetId() })
```

Full example ([Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nED1t874IWT)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mapCollector[K comparable, V any] struct {
    GetKey func(result V) K
}

func (m mapCollector[K, V]) Collect(result V) K {
    return m.GetKey(result)
}

type UserId string

type User struct {
    Id UserId
}

func (u User) GetId() UserId {
    return u.Id
}

func MakeUserMapCollector[K comparable, V any](collect func(result V) K) *mapCollector[K, V] {
    return &mapCollector[K, V]{
        GetKey: collect,
    }
}

func main() {
    u := User{
        Id: "12",
    }

    mc := MakeUserMapCollector[UserId, User](func(result User) UserId { return result.GetId() })
    fmt.Println(mc.Collect(u))
}
```